# Help with China TST 2011 geometry problem:

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, contest-math

> (China TST 2011) Let $\Gamma$ be the circumcircle of a triangle $ABC$. Assume $AA', BB',CC'$ are diameters of $\Gamma$. Let $P$ be a point inside $\triangle ABC$ and let $D, E, F$ be the feet from $P$ to $BC, CA, AB$. Let $X$ be the reflection of $A'$ across $D$; define $Y$ and $Z$
> similarly. Prove that $\triangle XYZ\sim\triangle ABC$.

I found this problem and tried to use complex numbers to solve it, but every time it failed. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my computations?

First, I defined $\Gamma$ to be the unit circle. Then, its easy to notice that $a' = - a$ , $b' = -b$  and $c' = -c$ ( Since zero is the midpoint, and thus $\frac{1}{2} (a + a') = 0 \implies a' = -a$). As $D$ is the midpoint of $A'$ and $X$, we have $d = \frac12(x + a') = \frac12(x - a) \implies x = 2d + a$. Similarly, $y = 2e + b$ and $z = 2f + c$. Now the only thing left is to express $d$, $e$ and $f$  in therms of $p$. As $A$, $B$ and $C$ lie on the unit circle, we can use the formula: "given $T$ and $S$ on the unit circle and a point $H$, then the foot from $H$ to $TS$ is:
$$\frac12( t + s + h - ts\bar{h})$$
where $\bar{h}$ is the conjugate of $h$"

And thus

\begin{align*}
x &= 2d + a = a + b + c + p - bc\bar{p},\\
y &= a + b + c + p - ca\bar{p}\\
z &= a + b + c + p - ab\bar{p}
\end{align*}

For the triangles to similar, we must have $(c - a)/(b - a) = (z - x)/(y - x)$, but
$$
\frac{z - x}{y - x} = \frac{\bar{p}b( c - a)}{\bar{p}c(b - a)} = \frac{b(c - a)}{c (b - a)}
$$
This means: $(c - a)/(b - a) = (b(c - a))/(c(b - a)) \implies b = c$, which is a lie.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. could you provide a figure?

Comment: Where did the $+p$ go in your formula for $y,z$?  It should be $y=a+b+c+p-ac\bar{p}$ if you keep the cyclic symmetry.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put the +p, thanks for the warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{z-x}{y-x}=\frac{ab-bc}{ac-bc}=\frac{1/c-1/a}{1/b-1/a}=\frac{\bar{c}-\bar{a}}{\bar{b}-\bar{a}}$$

This means $\triangle XYZ$ is inversely similar to $\triangle ABC$. That is if $A,B,C$ are oriented counter-clockwise, $X,Y,Z$ are oriented clockwise.

Since the triangle formed by $\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c}$ is reflection of that formed by $a,b,c$ in real axis, it has its orientation flipped.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did not remember that the orientation could affect the answer, so I was endlessly searching for a computation error with x, y and z